# An error in matplotlib related to numpy.roots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I was trying to plot (the modulus of) sum of quadratic roots and it returns me an error illustrated as follow:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rooting(a, b, c):
    y = [a, b, c]
    z = np.roots(y)
    return np.absolute(z[0]+z[1])

x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
plt.plot(x, rooting(x, 2, 3))
```

and the error was:

```
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 1570, in nonzero
    res = nonzero()

SystemError: <built-in method nonzero of numpy.ndarray object at 0x000001422B9BFD00> returned a result with an error set
```

Can someone tell me what's going on?

Comment: Getting a `SystemError` is probably a numpy bug.  Even if you did something wrong, you should get a standard exception such as `ValueError`,  `TypeError`, or the catch-all `RuntimeError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises because you are passing the variable to a vector and then concatenate with b and c are numbers, you must pass to the variable to a scalar, I show my next solution based on the above.

```
def rooting(a, b, c):
    y = [a, b, c]
    z = np.roots(y)
    return np.absolute(z[0]+z[1])

x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
y = [rooting(xi, 2, 3) for xi in x]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: but how come it works for simple function like plt.plot(x, x**2)?

Comment: It is that the `**` operator is overloaded for numpy vectors and matrices.

Comment: Instead the concatenation does not assume it, since if you pass an `x = [1, 2, 3]` and then execute: `y = [x, 2, 3]`, this equals `ay = [[1,2,3], 1, 2]`

Comment: And the roots function requires a vector or list of scalars, this does not require a list of list.

Comment: If you want to check it you can print `y` after the next line `y = [a, b, c]`

Comment: Yes your solution is correct, and I am really grateful for that. But I just realized that I asked my question in a pretty bad way. This is my first time using Stack Overflow so I am not so sure what to do......should I make an edit or just delete the post and make a new one?

Comment: You could mark my answer as correct and create a new question in which I could also help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the quadratic formula, we know the roots are `(-b ± √(b**2-4ac))/2a`.
So the modulus of the sum of the roots is `|b/a|`.
With this simplification, we can compute the result in a vectorized way (no list comprehesion, looping, or multiple calls of `rooting` necessary):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rooting(a, b, c):
    # The roots are (-b ± √(b**2-4ac))/2a
    # So the modulus of the sum of the roots is |b/a|
    return np.abs(b/a)

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)
plt.plot(x, rooting(x, 2, 3))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your method certainly would work for this particular function that I illustrated, but I was working with a more complex function that deals with the roots of polynomial. Thank you very much for your help anyway.